# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in swift(SKProduct)

Tags: xcode, swift, error-handling, fatal-error, skproduct

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import StoreKit

extension SKProduct {
func localizedPrice() -> String {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
    return formatter.stringFromNumber(self.price)!
}
}


class BuyCoin: SKScene {

var coin200a = SKProduct()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
NSLog("The price of this product is \(coin200a.localizedPrice())")
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
PS: I am trying to get the local price of an in-app purchase product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [DOCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKProduct/price) `price` of `SKProduct` might be `nil` in case if `SKProduct` was not configured properly.

```
var price: NSDecimalNumber! { get } // suppose crash happens here
```

API demands from user to configure `SKProduct` with all proper values otherwise it will crash when you try to unwrap `price` that actually is `nil`

---

*For testing:*

I would write something like:

```
if self.price != nil{ // we don't unwrap price (fetch optional)
   return formatter.stringFromNumber(self.price!)!
} 
else{
  return ""
}
```

Comment: But I have put the price of the in-app purchase with product ID "coin200a" to Tier 1(0.99 usd), so it can't be nil??

Comment: I tried, it keeps returning "" and no price.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your answer helped out the error, but now it keeps returning "". But I need to get the price.. how?

Comment: if you got price `nil` means you didnt configure it properly.

Comment: the product id is "coin200a", and here i am using "var coin200a = SKProduct()", what do i have to configure more?

Comment: I never used `SKProduct` but showed you where is a problem, see my answer I edit